# Dependency injection using options pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection

I am building an application which uses dependency injection following the options pattern design. I have a custom ORM class named `DataManager`. When I create an instance of `DataManager` I inject the connection string into the class as below.

```
  public class DataManager : CommonDataManager {

    private readonly ConnectionStrings _connectionStrings;


    public DataManager(IOptions<ConnectionStrings> options) {

        this._connectionStrings = options.Value;


    }
```

When creating the `DataManager` object which parameter should I use? What should the initialisation code look like?

```
DataManager dm = new DataManager(?);
```

Comment: Normally, you do not need to manually instantiate DataManager class. Instead, you just register in DI (IoC) container, and let the container resolves it for you.

Comment: Here is an example blog. https://andrewlock.net/how-to-use-the-ioptions-pattern-for-configuration-in-asp-net-core-rc2/

Basically it should just work, as the DI will map IOptions<ConnectionString> to Options<ConnectionString>

Comment: 1. Options is not a design pattern. 2. You should refrain from letting your application components take a dependency on `IOption<T>`, because it has no function, as described [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetintegration.html#working-with-ioption-t). In your case, `DataManager` should simply depend on the `string` connectionString that it requires.

Answer (score 0):

DI integration means that the DI engine is going to be responsible for object creation. So instead of directly initializing your class, you should rather do the following. Register also your `DataManager` with DI, so you can later instantiate it from serviceCollection:

In your ConfigureServices method add the following:

```
services.AddTransient<DataManager>();
```

*Note, that you should decide the lifespan of your instance (I've chosen Transient here, but it's up to you - `Singletone`, `Scoped`, ...).*

And then when you need to instantiate it, call as follows:

```
serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<DataManager>();
```

If, however, you want to go with your approach and want to instantiate the `DataManager` yourself, you should get the parameter from IoC container as follows:

```
DataManager dm = new DataManager(sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<ConnectionStrings>>());
```

*Note: that in both cases I assume that you've already registered the options with the DI in your `Startup.ConfigureServices` method.*